# Codeigniter Form_Validation issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have issue with From_Validation in Codeigniter.

Everything work fine in localhost, but when I upload the script in the server (online) I get error.

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined offset: 0
>
> Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php
>
> Line Number: 226
>
> Line: 238 Function: set_rules
>
> Line: 315 Function: require_once

could you please help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: Your CodeIgniter version please?

Comment: Codeigniter: 3.1.0

Comment: Does this error appear when you submit a form? please post the controller's code

Comment: It is impossible to tell without your code.

Comment: Yes when I submit

Comment: The error in this line: foreach ($requried_fileds as $filed)
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules($filed['filedID'], $filed['filedCaption'], 'required|xss_clean');
        }

Comment: My guess is that one of $filed is bad. Try print_r in the foreach to make sure all the values are expected. Please post all relevant controller and model code in the question, a simple foreach isn't always enough to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to Rename First letter of your Filename and Controller to Uppercase. because codeigniter controller name work are case sensitive on server.